# Windows Azure Graph API to add an Application

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to use the Windows Azure Active Directory (WAAD) Graph API to add an application to my WAAD tenant.  I have successfully used the API to create users.  When using the API to add an application I receive an Authorization exception:

> Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Performing the same steps to add a user works without exception.

I followed the guide here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151791.aspx#BKMK_Configuring and the samples here:  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Write-Sample-App-for-79e55502 to get started.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
//get the tenantName
var tenantName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

// retrieve the clientId and password values from the Web.config file
var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

// get a token using the helper
var token = DirectoryDataServiceAuthorizationHelper.GetAuthorizationToken(tenantName, clientId, password);

// initialize a graphService instance using the token acquired from previous step
var graphService = new DirectoryDataService(tenantName, token);

// Create and save the application
var application = new Application();
application.availableToOtherTenants = false;
application.displayName = "some display name";
application.homepage = "https://localhost/";
application.identifierUris.Add("https://localhost/");
application.replyUrls.Add("https://localhost/");
graphService.AddTodirectoryObjects(application);
graphService.SaveChanges();
```

Do I need to setup rights to allow the creation of Applications via the Graph API?  I was unable to find a location in the Azure Management Console that allowed me to do this.

Am I using the correct code to add an Application?  There are not many examples on how to work with Applications.  I assume I need to use the AddTodirectoryObjects to save an Application because I am not finding an "AddTo..." method for Applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your service principal is in the wrong role. I guess it's under User Account Administrator role. Try to add it to other role e.g.: Company Adminstrator for testing purpose...

Comment: That was the issue.  I used PowerShell to update the role. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx.  'Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName "Company Administrator" -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId ...'